# KeyboardEvent on Mac Os

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'd like to add an KeyboardEvent on MacOs laptop.
Problem exist to capture ENTER. Indeed on laptop, you must press "fn" + RETURN to simulate ENTER.
But I don't see how to do that. Indeed, when I make a test it's like ENTER and RETURN is the same.
So it's a big problem for me, because, I'd like to add shortcut with ENTER key and let user the opportunity to use RETURN key.

Do you have an idea to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check, whether just 'fn' pressing fires keyboard event?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for the keyCode 13

```
protected function handleKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
       trace("enter/return pressed");
   }

}
```

This works for the os x return key as well as pc enter

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you are testing within Flash IDE to disable keyboard shortcuts during testing!

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps want to check for Keyboard.NUMPAD_ENTER in your keyboard handler?

```
private function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMPAD_ENTER)
    {
        trace("enter pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: I try that but on my laptop (macbook pro) fn+Enter is not egal to Keyboard.NUMPAD_ENTER. Thanks